# Solving an integral using uniroot

Tags: r

Suppose I have the following data

```
n<-100
ki <- runif(n)
yi<-rbinom(n,1,0.5)
u<-runif(n)
```

I would like to solve the equation

[image]

This is the same as solving

[image]

```
#Attempt: Not sure about this
library(rootSolve)
library(pracma)
Intz<-function(s){exp( ki* log( s))}
fz <- function(z){
       exp(yi)  * quadinf( Intz , xa=0, xb= z)$Q 
            +  log(u)
    } 
z <- uniroot(fz, interval=c(0, 1e3) )$root
z
```

I get the following error

```
Error in uniroot(h, interval = c(1, 1000), tol = .Machine$double.eps^0.5) : 
  f() values at end points not of opposite sign
```

I get the same error message when I try to solve
[image]

I should end up with n values of z.

Comment: I don't see `quadinf` in `LaplacesDemon` or `rootSolve`. It's in `pracma`, but the limits are `xa` and `xb` rather than `za` and `zb`. Also, you never defined `u`. What do you mean it "does not work"? If it returns an error, please copy the error.

Answer (score 1):

The integral of `exp(ki*log(s))` with respect to `s` from 0 to `z` is just `z^(ki + 1)/(ki + 1)`, so you can solve for `z`, no need for numeric root finding or integrals.

`z <- (-(ki + 1)*log(u)*exp(-yi))^(1/(ki + 1))`